# How to obtain size in bytes for set of keys in Redis?

Tags: redis

I have a use case where I need to obtain number of bytes for all the keys that match a regular expression.

- Is there a functionality similar to like `sizeof(keysmatch:*)`?
- If so, would that include size for all types of keys (sets, lists, etc)?

I understand I can use `MEMORY USAGE key`, however, I would need to pipe it to get all the values. Is that the best way?

From my understanding `DBSIZE` returns only the key count. Is there a functionality that returns the size of the db?

Answer (score 1):

**Is there a functionality similar to like sizeof(keysmatch:*)?**

NO. AFAIK, you have to use `MEMORY USAGE`.

**Is there a functionality that returns the size of the db?**

You can use `MEMORY STATS` to get the memory usage of the whole database.